# How to upload selected file with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to upload files to Google Drive, but the `< input type = "file">` tag does not exist in HTML. File selection window opens How can I select the file I want in this section?

Answer (score 0):

Pyautogui like so,

## hover over your position You want to click

## get coordinates

Import pyautogui

Pyautogui.position()
Use those coordinates to click
Pyautogui.click(x,y)